# Display image with react from strapi

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, fetch, strapi

i have a problem with fetching images from strapi .
i tried a lot but it wont show any images , also when i post rich text ad try image it wont work, can somebody help me out  !

```
const ApiUrl = ('http://localhost:1337')
```

const { id } = useParams()
const {loading , error , data } = useFetch('http://localhost:1337/reviews/ ' + id)

```
if(loading) return <p>Loading..</p>
if(error) return <p>Error</p>

return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <div className={classes.container}>
     
      <img src={ApiUrl + data.image} alt={data.naam} />
      <h2 className={classes.headertxt}>{data.naam}</h2>
```

also tried {review.image}    {data.image.url} review.image.url

regardss

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to check the documentation for your API (if you use rest API) or schema of GraphQl playground (if you use GrapQl).

Install [Swagger UI](https://strapi.io/documentation/developer-docs/latest/development/plugins/documentation.html#installation) documentation plugin to check schema.

This may fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can give you some directions.

[LINK TO STRAPI CONTENT API GET](https://strapi.io/documentation/developer-docs/latest/developer-resources/content-api/content-api.html#get-an-entry)

and this is what this should return for you:

```
{
      "id": 1,
      "title": "Restaurant 1",
      "cover": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "image.png",
        "hash": "123456712DHZAUD81UDZQDAZ",
        "sha256": "v",
        "ext": ".png",
        "mime": "image/png",
        "size": 122.95,
        "url": "http://localhost:1337/uploads/123456712DHZAUD81UDZQDAZ.png",
        "provider": "local",
        "provider_metadata": null,
        "created_at": "2019-12-09T00:00:00.000Z",
        "updated_at": "2019-12-09T00:00:00.000Z"
      },
      "content": [
        {
          "__component": "content.title-with-subtitle",
          "id": 1,
          "title": "Restaurant 1 title",
          "subTitle": "Cozy restaurant in the valley"
        },
        {
          "__component": "content.image-with-description",
          "id": 1,
          "image": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "image.png",
            "hash": "123456712DHZAUD81UDZQDAZ",
            "sha256": "v",
            "ext": ".png",
            "mime": "image/png",
            "size": 122.95,
            "url": "http://localhost:1337/uploads/123456712DHZAUD81UDZQDAZ.png",
            "provider": "local",
            "provider_metadata": null,
            "created_at": "2019-12-09T00:00:00.000Z",
            "updated_at": "2019-12-09T00:00:00.000Z"
          },
          "title": "Amazing photography",
          "description": "This is an amazing photography taken..."
        }
      ],
      "opening_hours": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "day_interval": "Tue - Sat",
          "opening_hour": "7:30 PM",
          "closing_hour": "10:00 PM"
        }
      ]
    }
```

Comment: thank you for the response ,
with the information you gave me , i tried review.foto.formats.thumbnail.url and that should display it , but i still dont see an image apearing  als i tried all of it, i think i missed something ,

Comment: @cendrickking maybe you can put some width and height for your img tag

` <img src={url} alt={data.naam}  style={{ width: 200px; height: 200px }}/>`

something like that, have you tried this ?

Comment: yess also didnt work , i have now installed documentation api , and tried numerous things , when i find it it let know

Comment: we can help more if you put your here

https://codesandbox.io/